# how to display message date wise and don't repeat the sate if date is same from array in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In below array "active" there are 4 values , I am trying to map this value and display message and date on ui. This is coming fine ,but every time date are getting repeat .like

```
2019-07-11
Hello 1
2019-07-11
hello 2
2019-07-10
hello 3
```

while I have to display value datewise if date is same don't repeat the date  .like

```
2019-07-11
Hello1
Hellow2
2019-07-10
hello 3
hello 4

   active: Array(4)
    0:
    created_at: "2019-07-11"
    date: "Today"
    message: "<p> Hello 1 </p>
    status: 1
    time: "07:01:41"
    title: "Telephone"
    __typename: "NotificationList"

    1:
    created_at: "2019-07-11"
    date: "Today"
    message: "<p> Hello 2 </p>
    status: 1
    time: "06:59:38"
    title: "MSISDN"
    __typename: "NotificationList"

    2:
    created_at: "2019-07-10"
    date: "Today"
    message: "<p> Hello 3 </p>
    status: 1
    time: "06:57:08"
    title: "Telecom BSS"
    __typename: "NotificationList"

    3:
    created_at: "2019-07-10"
    date: "Today"
    message: "<p> Hello 4 </p>
    status: 1
    time: "06:57:08"
    title: "Telecom BSS"
    __typename: "NotificationList"

// Here am maping active array 
{notifications.notificationList.active.map((data,index) =>{
           const datahtml=data.message;
           const datee=formatDateTime(data.created_at);
           return(
             <View key={index}>
              <View style={{flexDirection:'column', backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                <Label text= {`${datee}`}/>
                <Heading title={`${data.title}`} time={`${data.time}`}/>

                <HTML html={datahtml} imagesMaxWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width} />
              </View>

            </View>
           )
           })}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fetch all dates and store it in a list. Then check each element date with this list if exist, then append the result in a new map with date as a key and value as a message.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of something like it was already suggested, I think it would be better to transform your array into something you can work with, like an object which has the date as a key and the individual items as an array value.

To achieve this, you can use `Array.reduce` like

```
const byDate = array.reduce((obj, item) => {
    if(obj[item.created_at]) {
        obj[item.created_at].push(item);

        return obj;
    }

    obj[item.created_at] = [
      {...item}
    ];
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Then your data structure will look like this

```
{
    '2019-07-11': [
        {
            created_at: '2019-07-11',
            date: 'Today',
            message: '<p> Hello 1 </p>',
            status: 1,
            time: '07:01:41',
            title: 'Telephone'
        }
        {
            created_at: '2019-07-11',
            date: 'Today',
            message: '<p> Hello 2 </p>',
            status: 1,
            time: '06:59:38',
            title: 'MSISDN'
        }
    ],
    '2019-07-10': [
        {
            created_at: '2019-07-10',
            date: 'Today',
            message: '<p> Hello 3 </p>',
            status: 1,
            time: '06:57:08',
            title: 'Telecom BSS'
        },
        {
            created_at: '2019-07-10',
            date: 'Today',
            message: '<p> Hello 4 </p>',
            status: 1,
            time: '06:57:08',
            title: 'Telecom BSS'
        }
    ]
}
```

And then you could manipulate this object more easy by going something like this

```
<View>
    {Object.keys(byDate).map(date => (
        <View>
            <Text>{date}</Text> /* Will display the date */
            <View>
                {byDate[date].map(item => <Text>{item.message}</Text>)} /* Then for each date display the message */
            </View>
        </View>
    ))}
</View>
```

I did not use your markup, so please adapt this markup to your needs. I am not sure how performant something like this is for very long arrays, but that's for you to research. Good luck.